# How to get selecteditem changed of dropdownlist in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

My scenario is to navigate to particular `category page` when a user select the object from the `dropdown list`. And this is to be done using angular js.

what ng tag to be used for on-selected index changed event

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="ddlcategories" ng-change="changeValue(categoryId)" DataTextField="CategoryName" DataValueField="CategoryId" ></asp:DropDownList>
```

I have a written some function

```
$scope.changeValue = function($value){
  window.location.href = baseUrl + "/" + $scope;
}
```

How do I achieve this? The above function is not working.

Comment: Try use  `ngModel="categoryId"` as well. By the way what is `baseUrl + "/" + $scope`, $scope will be an object.

Comment: baseUrl is basically a variable having value of url. for eg http://www.example.com/items

Comment: I am not asking about baseUrl i am asking about adding $scope object

Comment: $scope is the general object of ctrlFunc

Comment: I know what is $scope..  :) I am asking what do you expect after concatinating object to a string, you will just get the string representation of the object's type i.e `someurl/[object Object]` i am sure you did not mean that.